# Mocking import which brings in two aliases

Tags: typescript, momentjs, jestjs

I'm attempting to write unit tests in Jest to mock several portions of code utilizing the moment.js library. For completeness, this is a Node+Express project, written as TypeScript with the supporting `moment.d.ts` file.

The import and code block I'm attempting to test:

`import moment from 'moment';`

```
const durationSinceLastEmail = moment.duration(moment(new Date())
                .diff(moment(user.passwordRecoveryTokenRequestDate)));
```

Type information provided for the imported moment reference list two actual items:

```
(alias) function moment(inp?: moment.MomentInput, format?: moment.MomentFormatSpecification, strict?: boolean): moment.Moment (+1 overload)
(alias) namespace moment
import moment
```

My implementing code uses both forms: `moment.duration` for the namespace, and `moment(...params)` for the function.

My general Jest mocking strategy has not been very effective. Ex)

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => {
        return {
            duration: (...params) => mockDuration(...params)
        };
    });
});
```

I have been successful in mocking the duration function by directly replacing the duration method in a bit more of a forceful manner.

```
const originalDuration: Function = moment.duration;

mockDuration.mockImplementation((...params) => {
    const original = originalDuration(...params);
    // Apply mocks on returning object here
    // or supply entirely new mock object
    return original;
});

moment.duration = mockDuration;
```

Frankly, the code is pretty gross, but it's getting me half way there, as this allows me to capture calls to `moment.duration(...params)`, but every method I've tried for mock the `moment(...)` call has either not worked or completely clashes with the approach above (and also does not work).

The naming conflict seems to be the source of my problems, so my question would be:

1) Is there anyway for me to separate these different references out so that they can be dealt with explicitly?

or

2) Is there an effective way for me to mock them separately, or otherwise supply mocking for both the function and the namespace in a single mock object?

Comment: it sounds like you are most interested in spying on the calls to `moment()` and `moment.duration()` and are less interested in replacing their implementations, is that right?

Comment: Spying on these is fine - however, I would like to mock the implementation of the `diff()` function (provided on returned object from moment()) - I had been trying to mock moment() in order to get access to this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) for `moment` and give it whatever implementation you want.

Create `__mocks__/moment.js` at the root of your project next to `node_modules`:

```
const momentMock = jest.fn();  // create the moment mock
momentMock.mockImplementation(() => ({ diff: jest.fn() }));  // give it a mock implementation

momentMock.duration = jest.fn();  // add the moment.duration mock

export default momentMock;  // export the mock
```

Call `jest.mock('moment');` in your test to use the mock:

```
import moment from 'moment';

jest.mock('moment');  // use the mock

test('durationSinceLastEmail', () => {
  const user = {
    passwordRecoveryTokenRequestDate: new Date('2019-01-01')
  }
  const durationSinceLastEmail = moment.duration(moment(new Date())
    .diff(moment(user.passwordRecoveryTokenRequestDate)));

  expect(moment).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);  // SUCCESS
  expect(moment.duration).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. The only change I had to make was to convert the export to CommonJS syntax since it was a JS file rather than a TS file. `module.exports = momentMock;  // export the mock`